# ObjectAnimator#of*メソッドの第二引数に指定するString propertyNameについて

Tags: android, android-animation

Androidで画面遷移時にアニメーションさせるために
アニメーション作成の一部で例えば以下のように書いています。

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "x", containerSize.right, containerSize.left);
```

この第二引数がベタ書きなのが気になります。
ObjectAnimatorのクラス定数にそれ用の定数があるのでは？と見てみたのですが、
それらしいものは見当たりませんでした。

[AndroidでもiPhoneに負けないようなアニメーションを実装してみよう - Yahoo! JAPAN Tech Blog](http://techblog.yahoo.co.jp/programming/androidiphone/)
という記事でもベタ書きされているので`これはそういうもの`なのだとは思いますが、
本当にそれ用の定数が用意されていないのでしょうか？
こういう値が特定多数のものこそ定数として用意するべきだと思ったのですが。

Comment: マジックナンバーである"x"を置き換えるため、static final String X = "x"といった定数はないか、ということですか？

Comment: 第二引数のStringで自由に設定できる意味は何かしらあるのかもしれませんが、どこかにそれ用の定数があっておかしくないと考えていました。

Viewがそれ(Stringではなく[Property](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/view/View.html#X)ですが)を持っているとは考えてもみませんでした。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

View クラスにそれ用の定数 X があります。 (Y, ALPHA, ROTATION など、一通りあります。)
これを使って以下のように書けます。

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.X, ...
```